# Exclude Results With "NOT LIKE" (NOT LIKE "New % Application")

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a quick question about MySQL. I am trying to exclude the following results:
 "New Member Application",
 "New Developer Application"

Basically, "New X Application". However, this is my first time using "NOT LIKE". Here's the line of code:

```
'where'    => 't.approved = 1 AND t.title NOT LIKE "New % Application"',
```

I already know I am doing this wrong because it doesn't work. Therefore, I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how to get this working. Of course I could use "NOT LIKE 'New Member Application%' AND NOT LIKE 'New Developer Application%'" but I want to make it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce it:

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7d073/2/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE tab(title VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO tab(title)
VALUES ("New Member Application"), ("New Developer Application"),("x");

SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE title NOT LIKE "New % Application";
```

Has your title whitespaces?

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(title)) NOT LIKE "New % Application";
```

Comment: You probably right, I tought in use `WHERE title NOT LIKE "%New % Application%"`

Comment: I believe this was the problem. Seems to work correctly now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `not in`?

```
t.approved = 1 AND t.title not in ('New Member Application', 'New Developer Application')
```

Comment: That does seem useful. However, I think it has to match the exact text. (I tried using the % signs and it didn't work). I might be wrong though. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  This formulation checks for the exact text.